# I want to transfer the "state" through a file

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a code like that :

```
class App extends Component {

        state = {
            active1: true,
            active2: false,
        }

        render() {
            if (this.state.active1) {

                <button onClick={() => {this.setState({ active1: false,
                                                        active2: true, })}
                />

            }

        }
```

I want to put this part of render() in another file (ex: Button.js) and then import it here like that :

```
class App extends Component {

        state = {
            active1: true,
            active2: false,
        }

        render() {
            if (this.state.active1) {
                return(
                    <Button />              // <== Here is the change
                )
            }

        }
```

I already tried to do it, but I think I have to change something because when I do it, in React DevTool, I see that when I click the button, the state isn't changing

Comment: question not clear. Please reword.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Lucas! I'm having a hard time understanding what you are asking. Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) replicating your issue?

Comment: Just edited the post, do you understand what I need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take care of all the props given to your custom `Button` component.

You could e.g. call the `onClick` prop when the `button` element in your `Button` component is clicked.

**Example**

```
// Button.js
import React from "react";

export default function Button(props) {
  return <button onClick={props.onClick}> Click me </button>;
}

// App.js
import React from "react";
import Button from "./Button.js";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active1: true,
    active2: false
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({
              active1: false,
              active2: true
            });
          }}
        />
        {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
function Button(props) {
  return <button onClick={props.onClick}> Click me </button>;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active1: true,
    active2: false
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({
              active1: false,
              active2: true
            });
          }}
        />
        {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the thing is I want to do that in another file like Button.js and then import it in this file because I have 4 buttons like that (then 4 states) and the file is becoming very big.

Comment: @LucasMahé Ok. I will update the answer. [You can take a look at this example of how to import it](https://codesandbox.io/s/01njo23w4v).